# US / Mexican border data

Tags: line, united-states, administrative-boundaries, data, mexico

I'm interested in locating free GIS shapefile data representing the US / Mexican border. I have found a point layer depicting the border crossing points but I'm interested in a polyline feature representing the actual border.

Comment: Texas Sector boundaries may follow County edges. You can get County Bnd's from Census.gov.

Comment: For open data I recommend researching/asking at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 7):

You can obtain the line shapefile for the Mexican border from the [U.S. Geological Survey](http://borderhealth.cr.usgs.gov/datalayers.html) website (or click [here](http://txpub.usgs.gov/BEHI/Data_download/Boundaries_Layers/International_Boundary_shp.zip) directly). Scroll down and from the list of **Categories**, select the *Boundaries* option. Then from the *Int Boundary* layer, click the *Shapefile* link:

[image: Boundary]

[image: Highlighted boundary with OpenLayers]

You will also get the length of each line feature (as the boundary is broken up into segments).

[image: Length of each line feature]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks everyone for the rapid and helpful answers appreciate everyone taking the time to reply. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes INEGI can help! from our side (México), and depends of what you want to do with that, look in this site:

http://www.inegi.org.mx/geo/contenidos/geoestadistica/m_geoestadistico_2014.aspx

click in "Areas geoestadisticas estatales"

Answer (score 2):

There are a multitude of potential sources for this, but the US State Department Office of the Geographer is the authoritative US source for international boundaries.  The Large Scale International Boundaries (LSIB) dataset is the reference work from which all maps generated by the US government are to be derived. The Humanitarian Information Unit has a [distribution website for LSIB data](https://hiu.state.gov/data/data.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

For country borders and those on lower administrative levels, have a look at [gadm](http://www.gadm.org/). I think the datasets are free for non-commercial use.

Answer (score 0):

International Boundary & Water Commission USA and Mexico has a link of GIS.

http://www.ibwc.state.gov/GIS_Maps/GIS_Links.html